# jquery mobile separate HTML page change when swipe

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have made 3 different html pages and I set anchor as [data-ajax="false"] to move another page.

Is there any way to change the page when swipe left or right ?

Also How do I set page change  transition ?

```
<a href="page1.html" data-ajax="false">page1</a>
<a href="page2.html" data-ajax="false">page2</a>
<a href="page3.html" data-ajax="false">page3</a>
```

Comment: you can use _swipe_ but transition won't work because _ajax_ is disabled. Pages will be loaded via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SlideMe  (http://slideme.luigiferraresi.it/) ?

There are many jQuery slideshow plugins and it is usually hard to decide which one is better.

SlideMe is a responsive jQuery slider. It is done using CSS3 and works smoothly even in IE7. It is easy to install and has full screen option.

I use this plugin (which I modified a little) and I'm satisfied.

Nicolas

Comment: Your answer isn't related to the question. OP is asking how to disable Ajax and switch pages with _animation_.